# Converting html to pdf using Python Flask

Tags: python, flask

Here is my code in myclass.py

```
class Pdf():

    def render_pdf(self,name,html):


        from xhtml2pdf import pisa
        from StringIO import StringIO

        pdf = StringIO()

        pisa.CreatePDF(StringIO(html), pdf)

        return pdf
```

And I am calling it in api.py like this

```
@app.route('/invoice/<business_name>/<tin>', methods=['GET'])
def view_invoice(business_name,tin):

   #pdf = StringIO()
  html = render_template('certificate.html', business_name=business_name,tin=tin)
file_class = Pdf()
pdf = file_class.render_pdf(business_name,html)
return pdf
```

But it throws this error

```
AttributeError: StringIO instance has no __call__ method
```

Answer (score 6):

The following script worked well for me. Note the changes I made:

- `Pdf.render_pdf()` now returns `pdf.getvalue()`, a `str`.
- `view_invoice()` now returns a tuple, so that the Content-Type header can be set.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)


class Pdf():

    def render_pdf(self, name, html):

        from xhtml2pdf import pisa
        from StringIO import StringIO

        pdf = StringIO()

        pisa.CreatePDF(StringIO(html), pdf)

        return pdf.getvalue()


@app.route('/invoice/<business_name>/<tin>',  methods=['GET'])
def view_invoice(business_name, tin):

    #pdf = StringIO()
    html = render_template(
        'certificate.html', business_name=business_name, tin=tin)
    file_class = Pdf()
    pdf = file_class.render_pdf(business_name, html)
    headers = {
        'content-type': 'application.pdf',
        'content-disposition': 'attachment; filename=certificate.pdf'}
    return pdf, 200, headers


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Man, you just saved my life. Please how can I rate you? And also, the filename that came up is response, how can I change that to View certificate

Comment: @OladapoAdebowale You can click the tick mark next to the answer to accept the answer as what worked out for you.

Comment: @OladapoAdebowale, it might help to add a `content-disposition` header. Use either `content-disposition: attachment; filename=certificate.pdf` or `content-disposition: inline; filename=certificate.pdf`. See my recent edit.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work with Python 3.5 or more...